# How to reset HP Laserjet 1102 driver?

Tags: printing, hp

I have an HP Laserjet P1102 printer which worked fine until today. For some reason, one particular print job would not print.

I deleted the job and tried again with no luck. I ever turned off the printer, disconnected it from the computer and logged out and in again to no avail.

Then, I tried deleting the printer and installing it again and it started working again.

So, is there a way to "reset" the printer without removing it and adding it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `/var/spool/cups` and delete all files, but leave the `tmp` directory.

Comment: I'll try it the first time it happens.

Comment: Is there an "automatic" way of avoiding this issue altogether?

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, that is, why this print job does not get printed. If everything worked as it should, the directory `/var/spool/cups` would be empty after the last print job. Of course you could set up a script to clear the directory at boot time, for instance.

Comment: That's a better question: How do I troubleshoot? I noticed that, on one occasion, connecting the printer to a different USB port made the printer work. Since then I'm connecting the printer to the same USB port but the problem remains.

Comment: If you think the problem is related to the printing process, look in `/var/log/cups/`. If you think it is to do with how the printer is connected to the USB port, take a look at `/var/log/dmesg`.